# Android - Removing Item from GridView/Adapter

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have an GridView filled by an Adapter

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

The dataset of the Adapter is basicly a shuffled List

```
static List<Integer>  mTlist = Arrays.asList(
    R.drawable.ac_pre, R.drawable.acc_pre,
    R.drawable.acd_pre, R.drawable.ach_pre,
    R.drawable.acs_pre, R.drawable.ad_pre,
    R.drawable.ah_pre, R.drawable.as_pre,
    R.drawable.dc_pre, R.drawable.dd_pre,
    R.drawable.dh_pre, R.drawable.ds_pre,
    R.drawable.fc_pre, R.drawable.fd_pre,
    R.drawable.fh_pre, R.drawable.fs_pre,
    R.drawable.jc_pre, R.drawable.jd_pre,
    R.drawable.jh_pre, R.drawable.js_pre,
    R.drawable.kc_pre, R.drawable.kd_pre,
    R.drawable.kh_pre, R.drawable.ks_pre,
    R.drawable.nc_pre, R.drawable.nd_pre,
    R.drawable.nh_pre, R.drawable.ns_pre,
    R.drawable.qc_pre, R.drawable.qd_pre,
    R.drawable.qh_pre, R.drawable.qs_pre,
    R.drawable.sec_pre, R.drawable.sed_pre,
    R.drawable.seh_pre, R.drawable.ses_pre,
    R.drawable.sic_pre, R.drawable.sid_pre,
    R.drawable.sih_pre, R.drawable.sis_pre,
    R.drawable.vc_pre, R.drawable.vd_pre,
    R.drawable.vh_pre, R.drawable.vs_pre,
    R.drawable.xc_pre, R.drawable.xd_pre,
    R.drawable.xh_pre, R.drawable.xs_pre,
    R.drawable.zc_pre, R.drawable.zd_pre,
    R.drawable.zh_pre, R.drawable.zs_pre
    );

private void mischen() {
    Collections.shuffle(mTlist);
}
```

from an diffrent Activity after pressing a button i want to remove an item

```
            ImageAdapter imad = new ImageAdapter(getBaseContext());
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
            Integer pos = extras.getInt("draw");

            ImageAdapter.mTlist.remove(pos);
            imad.notifyDataSetChanged();

            finish();
```

pos is the position of the item in the `List (mTlist);` with `finish()` i go back to the GridView-Activity.

But the problem is, nothing changes at all! I checked with a toast the item on the position after the removing and it was the same as before.

Please help!
Greetings ueen

Comment: Your approach is not correct. Use startActivityForResult to return the desired item to be deleted from the adapter. You can get an idea from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/786337

Comment: ok, tried out - now the app crashes...

Comment: i guess i made a miskte with the extras, fixed it and it does nothing again...well everything exept the remove works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the list to delete an object of type *Integer* and that's not correct 'cause you use *ArrayList*. Try the following to delete your object

```
ImageAdapter.mTlist.remove(pos.intValue());
```

Regards.

Comment: But with "new ImageAdapter" i creating a new adapter!

Comment: ok switched the list to another class so its not messed up by setting a new Adapter (your suggestion) but still, nothing is removed....

Comment: check the edited answer. your making a mistake passing an *Integer* object to remove. Hope it solves the question.